# MySQL, поиск и удаление в столбце записей, которые содержат буквы

Tags: mysql

Имеется таблица MySQL, мне необходимо удалить записи, которые в определенном столбце содержат любые знаки, кроме цифр.

Назовем этот столбец name, в нем есть записи цифрового типа (01, 0001, 0314, 41250 и т.д), тип ячейки varchar. В данном столбце есть записи, где помимо цифр есть и латинские буквы, выглядит это следующим образом (01MM314, 41YY3 и т.д). Мне необходимо удалить все записи в столбце которого есть любые символы, кроме цифр. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Не надо гуглить, надо читать документацию. [REGEXP_LIKE() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like)

Comment: @Akina Смог удалить с помощью: DELETE FROM db WHERE `name` REGEXP('[A-Z]')

Comment: REGEXP - это не функция!

Comment: @Akina тем не менее именно в виде функции оно "сработало" :)

Comment: Ну это MySQL тебе просто простил такое небрежение синтаксисом. Хотя должно было быть ```DELETE FROM db WHERE name REGEXP '[A-Z]';``` - синтаксически это оператор.